# Does backbone model has any id assigned by backbone framework

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

Is there an id assigned to an backbone model to identify it uniquely by Backbone.js? If Yes how to access it?

The situation is that I have an collection of models which is shown as an grid view having one checkbox in each row and If the checkbox ids check I want to get the checked row model.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [cid](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid)?, you can access it by:

```
model.cid
```

I don't think you need to use it, you can use [id](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id) or, if the model isn't saved to the database, a custom attribute to represent each model (for example a rowIndex).

```
model.id
model.get("customAttr")
```

And if the problem is accessing which model was checked I think you can use [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) on the checkboxes to access it from the view.

That's a lot of assumptions, but I hope it helped.

Comment: Yes, but there's no guarantee that a given cid won't be reused if a model is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

On the model you have the cid generated from backbone, you can get it with:

```
console.log( myModel.cid );
```

If you want the cid in your models JSON when handing over the models JSON representation to your template you could override the toJSON method of your model if you like:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  toJSON: function() {
    var json = _.clone(this.attributes);
    json.cid = this.cid;
    return json;
  }

});
```